# scan string with unknown number of elements to an array of int in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, strtok, scanf

I'm  working in a program in C and I have a char string of numbers like this:

```
5 13 12 7 3 0
```

I want to scan it and put each of these integers in an array of int. How do I do that?
Is that a way to use sscanf for this?

I tried the following code with no success:

```
 fgets(datatemp, N*3, stdin);

 k = 0; garb = 'c';
    while(garb != '\0'){
      garb = strtok(datatemp, " ");
      array[k] = garb;
      k++;
    }
```

NOTE: I have to use it in a function which will do the same for many data in which 'datatemp' string will have a unknown number of integers (and only integers).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take the whole input into a **string** using `getline()` and then split the string with the character " " and you will have an array of your numbers as strings. Convert your numbers from string to integer. This will give you your desired integer array.

Comment: array[k] = atoi(garb);

Comment: Why don't you directly read from `stdin` into `array`, till `scanf` is successfully

Comment: Is the count of `int` limited by `N` or is it an "unknown number" such as 0,1,2,3,...

Comment: At the end I just did what @P0W said.
But I still trying to do the other way, since it can be usefull in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Adapted from strtok(3) example.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *str1, *str2, *token, *subtoken;
  char *saveptr1,*saveptr2;
  int j;
  char datatemp[ 120 ];
  char delim = ' ';

  fgets(datatemp, 119, stdin);

  /*
   * strtok has to be called with a pointer to the input
   * the first time then with a pointer to the string
   * subsequently
   */

  for(j=1, str1 = datatemp;; j++, str1 = NULL)
  {
    token = strtok_r(str1, &delim, &saveptr1);

    if(token==NULL)
      break;

    for (str2 = token; ; str2 = NULL)
    {
      subtoken = strtok_r(str2, &delim, &saveptr2);
      if (subtoken == NULL)
        break;
      printf(" --> %s\n", subtoken);
    }
  }

  exit(0);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seeing as the code is rather complex, it would surely be of help to the OP if you could add some explanation, via inline comments or a text besides the code.

Comment: Note: No need to subtract 1, use `fgets(datatemp, 120, stdin);` or even better `fgets(datatemp, sizeof datatemp, stdin);`.  `fgets()` already accounts for the `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `strtol` in a loop, is faster (direct convert without an intermediate buffer) and you can check for errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[128], *p, *q;
    int i, n, *v;

    /* get user input */
    fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);
    /* count integers */
    for (p = s, n = 0; ; p = q, n++) {
        strtol(p, &q, 10);
        if (p == q) break;
    }
    v = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    /* populate array */
    for (p = s, i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v[i] = strtol(p, &p, 10);
    }
    /* print array */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", v[i]);
    }
    free(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard function `strtol` declared in header `<stdlib.h>`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>


int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "5 13 12 7 3 0";
    size_t l = strlen( s );

    size_t n = 0;

    char *end_ptr = s;
    char **next_ptr = &end_ptr;

    errno = 0;

    while ( end_ptr != s + l )
    {
        strtol( *next_ptr, next_ptr, 10 );
        if ( errno != 0 ) break;
        ++n;
    }

    int a[n];
    memset( a, 0, n * sizeof( int ) );

    end_ptr = s;
    size_t i = 0;
    while ( end_ptr != s + l )
    {
        int value = ( int )strtol( *next_ptr, next_ptr, 10 );
        if ( errno != 0 ) break;
        a[i++] = value;
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    puts( "" );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
5 13 12 7 3 0
```

Comment: Note: Before 2nd `while` loop, suggest another `errno = 0;`. Not confident about the the benefit of checking for `errno` and not checking if `(int)` loses range.  Suggest simply using `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: @chux In C atoi is defined as (int) strtol(...).:)

Comment: `atoi()` loses information should `sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)` just like `(int) strtol()`.  If code is concerned with `errno` (overflow), it is reasonable to also be concerned with losing data due to an `(int)` cast.  IAC, these issues are likely beyond OP's major concern.

Comment: Is it just me, or does your input not match your output? `0` is still and integer right?

Comment: @David C. Rankin It is a good remark! The condition has to be changed to endptr != s + strlen( s )

Comment: Good. I was going to offer the quick hack of `else if (*end_ptr == '\0') { ++n; break; }` after your first `if`, but I like your solution better.

Answer (score 0):

To use `fgets()/sscanf()` as requested by OP, see below.

Using `fgets()/strtol()` offers better error handling than `sscanf()`.   Recommend `strtol()`

To get the best answer, OP needs to provide info like how data is to be store (VLA, malloc, 1 at-a time), error handle concerns, etc.

Hard to tell why OP code did not work as the defalcation of `array[]` is missing, but it may have been too small for the test data and certain was not resized as needed for various data input.

```
void foo() {
  char buf[100];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();

  int i = 0;
  int n = 0;
  int number;
  // Count the numbers
  while (sscanf(&buf[i], "%d %n", &number, &i) == 1) {
    n++;
  }

  int num[n];
  i = 0;
  int j;
  // scan again, this time save the numbers
  while (sscanf(&buf[i], "%d %n", &num[i], &j) == 1) {
    i = j;
  }

  // use the numbers
  bar(num, n);
}
```

---

Above code could use likely skip the `j` and use `while (sscanf(&buf[i], "%d %n", &num[i], &i) == 1);`, but I need to double check some code-point issues.

`strtol()` is better than `sscanf()`.  To use, suggest a helper function:

```
// return non-zero on failure 
static int user_strtoi(char **s, int *result) {
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long num = strtol(*s, &endptr, 10);
  if (endptr == *s) return 1; //  fail as nothing was parsed
  if (errno != 0) return 2; //  fail due to overflow
  if (num < INT_MIN || num > INT_MAX)  return 2; //  fail due to overflow
  *result = (int) num;
  *s = endptr;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: array[] is a array of integers dynamically allocated with malloc to fit a maximum size of numbers defined in the input file. Also, array[] is inside a struct vector that is dynamically allocated too.

Comment: @user3442466 Suggest updating your post so the _code_ includes this important clarification.  Also post a larger example of sample data.  1) Multi-line? 2) Each lines same number of `int`? 3)  Given you appear to want an array of "array of integers", Do _all_ the "array of integers" need to be the same length? 4) how do you want to denote the length of `int` in the "array of integers"? 5) How do you want to denote the length of the array of "array of integers"?